# How to make Tomcat 8.5 RewriteValve work with AJP1.3 JKMount?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8

## Premise

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server with the latest Apache2 installed, I've different Virtual Hosts, 
each one properly configured (and secured with Let's Encrypt):

> - /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**my.site.com-le-ssl.conf**
> - /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**my.other.site.com-le-ssl.conf**

pointing to static content under:

> - /var/www/my.site.com/
> - /var/www/my.other.site.com/

**This works fine**: 
by calling `https://my.site.com/` I see the static site that is contained in `/var/www/my.site.com/`.

I've then [installed Tomcat 8.5.9](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [secured it with a reverse proxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04), hence adding:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>
    . . .
    JKMount /* ajp13_worker
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**my.site.com-le-ssl.conf** .

**This also works fine**:
by calling `https://my.site.com/` now I see the Tomcat home.

---

## Desired Goal

I want to achieve the following result:

- by calling `https://my.site.com/` I want to see the static site (`/var/www/my.site.com/`);
- by calling `https://my.site.com/dynamic` I want to see the Tomcat home;
   hence,
  by calling `https://my.site.com/dynamic/myApp` I expect to run `myApp.war` published under `tomcat/webapps`;

## Attempted solution

My idea was the following:

- make Apache JKMount-ing only the requests with the `/dynamic` context, hence instead of:

  ```xml
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      . . .
      JKMount /* ajp13_worker
      . . .
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  , I've used:

  ```xml
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      . . .
      JKMount /dynamic/* ajp13_worker
      . . .
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

and **this appears to works**, on the Apache side; calling `my.site.com` will open the static content, while calling the `my.site.com/dynamic` will give Tomcat 404.

Now I need to rewrite the URL to remove the `dynamic` context, in order to make it transparent to Tomcat, and I've tried for the last 3 hours to do that with the [Tomcat RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html):

- I've edited `tomcat/conf/server.xml` by adding the Valve:

  ```xml
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      . . .
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
  </Host>
  ```
- I've created a `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` file, containing the right rule (tested [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)):

  ```xml
  RewriteRule ^dynamic/(.+)$ /$1
  ```

For some reason, this does not work. The Tomcat's RewriteValve rule is either ignored, or malfunctioning, or there's something wrong in the way I thinked the whole thing... I'm not a sysadmin, so I'd not be surprised by some naive error here.

Do you see where the problem is ? Or another way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using `mod_proxy_ajp` instead of `mod_jk`.

Apache's **my.site.com-le-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    . . .
    ProxyPass        /dynamic/ ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse /dynamic/ ajp://localhost:8009/
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat's **rewrite.config**

```
RewriteRule ^dynamic(.+)$ dynamic/$1/ [R]
```

Now it works as desired.